# [C++] tag blows up other tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

To Repro:

1. Search for the [c++] tag with another (e.g. "[c++] [php]", though all tags fail when accompanied by c++)

Result:

- No results are shown. Likely for [c++][php], but not for [c][c++] which are known to have some.
- The question tags on the right show either "[c+++other]" or "[other] [c] [] []"

Expected Result:

- The ++ part of [c++] should be properly recognized as being part of the tag

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20c%2b%2b
works. Unfortunately, every browser i've tried uses + for spaces in queries, and that breaks things...

(I would certainly consider this a bug in SO however; it should be able to differentiate between `+` and `%2b`...)

Comment: My point exactly